# Java type for any class that implements an interface

Tags: java

We have:

```
  intercace ISomething { ... }
  class A implements ISomething { ... }
  class B extends A { ... }
```

Would like to have a type for all classes that implement `ISomething`, so that:

```
  Class<ISomething> klass;
  klass = new A.class;
  klass = new B.class;
```

are all valid. The code as-is doesn't compile.
What can I use to replace the type `Class<ISomething>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
Class<? extends ISomething> clazz = B.class;
clazz = A.class;
clazz = ISomething.class;
// all valid
```